# I must disable submenu mfc c++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I must disable an item of submenu, I tried:

```
CMenu* pMenu = AfxGetMainWnd()->GetMenu();
CMenu* pSubMenu = pMenu->GetSubMenu(1);
if (pMenu != NULL)
{
    //for (UINT i = 0; i < pMenu->GetMenuItemCount(); ++i)
        pSubMenu->EnableMenuItem(ID_FILE_CONFRONTO_GRAFICI, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_GRAYED);
        
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I must disable the second item of submenu

Comment: That is not right. If you use MF_BYPOSITION then pass the position and not the control ID.

Comment: Use Mf_BYCOMMAND if you want to use the menu item ID.

Comment: You should add to your Question that it didn't work and what happened instead.

Comment: I made some updates to your answer to make it more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue:

```
CMenu* pMenu = AfxGetMainWnd()->GetMenu();
CMenu * subMenu = pMenu->GetSubMenu(0);
if (subMenu != NULL)
{
        subMenu->EnableMenuItem(1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_DISABLED);

}
```

---

## Clarification

[`EnableMenuItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmenu-class?view=vs-2019#enablemenuitem) has the following definition:

> ```
> UINT EnableMenuItem(
>     UINT nIDEnableItem,
>     UINT nEnable);`
> ```

The important thing to understand is the correct use of the last `nEnable` parameter. To quote:

> *`nEnable`*
> Specifies the action to take. It can be a **combination** of
> `MF_DISABLED`, `MF_ENABLED`, or `MF_GRAYED`, with `MF_BYCOMMAND` or
> `MF_BYPOSITION`. These values can be combined by using the bitwise `OR`
> operator. These values have the following meanings:
>
> `MF_BYCOMMAND` Specifies that the parameter gives the **command ID of the
> existing menu item**. This is the default.
>
> `MF_BYPOSITION` Specifies that the parameter gives **the position of the
> existing menu item**. The first item is at position 0.

In the original code you had:

```
pSubMenu->EnableMenuItem(ID_FILE_CONFRONTO_GRAFICI, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_GRAYED);
```

The issue:

1. You used `MF_BYPOSITION` (which means `nIDEnableItem` is a zero based index) yet ...
2. You used `ID_FILE_CONFRONTO_GRAFICI` for the first parameter.

So there are two way to do this (with some exceptions):

- `subMenu->EnableMenuItem(1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_DISABLED);`
- `subMenu->EnableMenuItem(ID_FILE_CONFRONTO_GRAFICI, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_DISABLED);`